# Spotlight not showing Bing results on iOS 8

Tags: spotlight

I'm running iOS 8.0.2 on iPhone 5 and was really hyped about being able to get web search results from Spotlight.
Unfortunately whenever I type a query into Spotlight it doesn't display Bing results.

Any guesses on what the issue here could be? (Screenshot attached below)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There's only one location in Settings where I've seen reference to this. Try going to...

```
Settings > General > Spotlight Search
```

This is what I see when I go to those settings. You should be able to select the option there. If you don't see that option, you might try setting Bing as your default search engine for Safari. Let me know if that helps or what you find.

Hope that helps![image]

Comment: The problem is it is already set to that. I enabled all those options.